# Can not execute Azureus (Vuze)

Tags: 11.04, bittorrent, jre

I Downloaded Vuze from official site as tar.bz2 file. Set up JRE. Now if I try to execute it says

```
Starting Azureus...
Suitable java version found [java = 1.6.0_31]
Configuring environment...
Java exec found in PATH. Verifying...
Browser check failed with: Cannot load 64-bit SWT libraries on 32-bit JVM
Auto-scanning for GRE/XULRunner.  You can skip this by appending the GRE path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH and setting MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME.
  checking /usr/lib/firefox-11.0 for GRE
GRE found at /usr/lib/firefox-11.0.
Browser check failed with: Could not initialize class org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display
Can't create browser.  Will try to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH and hope Vuze has better luck.
setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH to: /usr/lib/firefox-11.0
setting MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME to: /usr/lib/firefox-11.0
Loading Azureus:
java -Xmx128m -cp "./Azureus2.jar:./swt.jar" -Djava.library.path="/home/apple/Downloads/azureus" -Dazureus.install.path="/home/apple/Downloads/azureus" -Dazureus.script="./azureus" -Dazureus.script.version=2 org.gudy.azureus2.ui.swt.Main 
file:/home/apple/Downloads/azureus/Azureus2.jar ; file:/home/apple/Downloads/azureus/swt.jar ; file:/home/apple/Downloads/azureus/
changeLocale: *Default Language* != English (India). Searching without country..
changeLocale: Searching for language English in *any* country..
changeLocale: no message properties for Locale 'English (India)' (en_IN), using 'English (default)'
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.gudy.azureus2.ui.swt.Main.<init>(Main.java:114)
    at org.gudy.azureus2.ui.swt.Main.main(Main.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.aelitis.azureus.launcher.MainExecutor$1.run(MainExecutor.java:37)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load 64-bit SWT libraries on 32-bit JVM
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(C.java:21)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:132)
    at org.gudy.azureus2.ui.swt.mainwindow.SWTThread.<init>(SWTThread.java:84)
    at org.gudy.azureus2.ui.swt.mainwindow.SWTThread.createInstance(SWTThread.java:63)
    at com.aelitis.azureus.ui.swt.Initializer.<init>(Initializer.java:162)
    ... 12 more
Exit from Azureus complete
No shutdown tasks to do
Azureus TERMINATED.
```

Is it caused by SWT.jar? How to get rid from this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have a word-size mismatch between your Vuze (in particular, the library called "SWT" used by Vuze) and JVM as indicated by the message "*Cannot load 64-bit SWT libraries on 32-bit JVM*" (appears multiple times). Possible reasons are:

- You have installed the wrong version of either Vuze or the JVM:

  - if you have a 32 bit system then you can only run the 32 bit version of the JVM and Vuze,
  - if you have a 64 bit system you should install the 64 bit JVM.
- There is a library mismatch on your system (altough I would imagine that this "SWT" library came bundled with the installer).

Comment: I have 32-bit system and 32-bit JVM. I have downloaded Vuze from its official site where they did not provide any choice for 32-bit and 64-bit system.

Comment: I downloaded SWT.jar for 32-bit from http://www.eclipse.org/swt/ and put this in azureus directory replacing original SWT.jar which came along tarball. whoa ! I can execute azureus now.

Comment: one question why they are giving only 64-bit SWT.jar with tarball ?

Comment: @virpara I am not familiar at all with Vuze, so I don't know why they aren't bundling both 32-bit and 64-bit versions.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 64 bit OS then take swt64.jar file from swt directory and put it into vuze directory and execute ./vuze script....Bingoooooooo

you got it

Regards,

Comment: alittle more detail please

Comment: @bodhi.zazen true but it fixed it for me :-) Also had to delete swt.jar after adding 64 to the vuze directory.